# How do I arrange buttons vertically in a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a text-based adventure game where the top of the screen is a JTextArea inside a JScrollPane that shows what is happening, and the bottom is a JOptionPane where you click on a button to make a choice. By default, the buttons are arranged horizontally. The only problem is that if I have too many buttons, there is no room for new ones and they are pushed off the screen. I need them to be arranged vertically since they are fatter than they are tall. The JOptionPane and the JScrollPane are nested in a gridLayout, which is nested in a JFrame. This is the method I am using to make the frame:

```
/**
 * Make the frame and everything in it
 */
private void makeFrame()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Adventure!");

    JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);       
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("font", Font.BOLD, 15));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    optionPane = new JOptionPane("", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, null);
    contentPane.add(optionPane);

    frame.pack();
    // place the frame at the center of the screen and show
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"and the bottom is a JOptionPane"* - Why?  The short answer to your question is, no. The long answer to your question is, do it yourself

Comment: But how do I apply a BoxLayout to the buttons inside a JOptionPane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
What would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Any number of things, a `JPanel` with `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` or even a [`WrapLayout`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/). You might want to but the panel in a `JScrollPane` as well

Comment: You create a custom `JDialog` and set its panel to a [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Comment: @user1803551:
 Maybe I'm a bit of a noob programmer, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do I need to make my own class that extends `JDialog`?

Comment: You can but you don't need to. Just create a [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) and add your panel to it. It behaves similarly to a `JFrame`.

Comment: `// place the frame at the center of the screen and show
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);` can be replaced by.. `// place the frame at the center of the screen and show
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @user1803551: how do I set the panel? Do I change it using the `setContentPane` method? Because that's not working for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Andrew :)

Comment: Would it be better if I just used `JButtons` in a `GridLayout`?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stack buttons vertically on a JOptionPane with JDialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205584/how-do-you-stack-buttons-vertically-on-a-joptionpane-with-jdialogs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `JOptionPane`, use `JButtons` in a `GridLayout`. You can specify how many components you want across and down upon creation like this: `new GridLayout(0, 3)`. This would result in 3 buttons stacked on top of each other, the first `int` being how many you want across, and the second, how many you want down. Try this:

```
/**
 * Make the frame and everything in it
 */
private void makeFrame()
{
frame = new JFrame("Adventure!");

JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);       
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setFont(new Font("font", Font.BOLD, 15));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
contentPane.add(textArea);


//This replaces your JOptionPane block
    buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    contentPane.add(buttonPane);

frame.pack();
// place the frame at the center of the screen and show
Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
```